# How to change or clone ONU pon mac adress? And I want to know which model of ONU will get this benefit

Tags: router, isp, mac-address

ISP is blocking me everytime from OLT my anu's MAC address.that's why I need to clone or change my MAC address.how can i change it. I would like to know if I will get this benefit if I use ONU of any brand or any model.

Comment: For those of us who, like me, have no clue what he is talking about https://community.fs.com/article/abc-of-pon-understanding-olt-onu-ont-and-odn.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have a look at https://hack-gpon.org/ont-fs-com-gpon-onu-stick-with-mac/, you need to clone the serial/mac address, and possibly others if your ISP requires them. Principally, you need a gpon with mac.